# How to get initial string from bytes encoded using StandardCharsets.US_ASCII?

Tags: java, string, byte

I need working code that will encode  and decode string to dn from byte. How can it be written so would be possible to have same result across all platforms?

```
String s = "test";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: String is Unicode (can combine Greek and Russian). `s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` is the all-platform solution. To print in the console as ASCII, convert to **Base64**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String`-class has a matching constructor:

```
String s = "test";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
String r = new String(b, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println(r);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code as you've written it will give the same result across all platforms.

There are two versions of the `getBytes()` method, one that takes an argument, and one that doesn't. The one that doesn't will use the default character set, which means the output will vary across platforms. But the one you've used, where you specify a character set, will give the same result everywhere.

(That said, you would probably be better off using UTF-8 rather than US_ASCII, because it'll be more forgiving with what characters you're allowed to have in your input string. But as long as you're consistent, it'll still give the same behaviour everywhere.)